# Is there a way to find the center point of this circle?

Tags: geometry

I am facing a problem that I have difficulty to solve.

I have a line that originates from the origin (point $(0,0)$) and has a known angle to the $x$ axis (angle $\theta$)

Somewhere between the $x$ axis and this line is a circle. This circle touches both lines, but the dimension and center of this circle are not known.

On the right side of the circle is a point $P$ that lies on the circumference of the circle and of which the coordinates are known.

How can I find the coordinates of the center of the circle?

I can't seem to add an image so I have used an external website to make the drawing.

========================================================

I now realize that I have over-simplified the problem because it is hard to explain in words. However, now I know that I can send a drawing in another way I would like to post the original problem:

You can see the drawing over [here](https://www.desmos.com/geometry/mfwj0suy8k)

There are two lines originating from the origin. The angle of each line in relation to the diagonal is the same and is known.
A circle is centered on the diagonal and only a 90 degrees arc of the circle is drawn between the lines.
On the arc of the circle is a point P of which the coordinates are known.
The dimension and location of the circle is not known, the only thing that is known is that point P lies on the arc and the arc is a 90 degrees segment of a circle with its center on the diagonal.

How can I find the coordinates of the circle?

Comment: A drawing would help a lot.  There seems to be enough information in the text, but it is hard to be sure.

Comment: With the new changes, you should consider posting a new problem instead

Answer (score 3):

A drawing of my understanding is below.  Please make sure it matches your understanding.  We know $\theta$ and the coordinates of $P$.  Because the circle is tangent to the two lines, $D$ is on the bisector of the angle.  That gives you the slope of the line from the origin through $D$, which gives a relationship between the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $D$.  You can now write the law of cosines for the triangle $ADP$ in terms of the $x$ coordinate of $D$ and solve the equation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick repley. However I can't visit https://i.stack.imgur.com - my browser says there is a problem with the site - so I can't see the image you have attached.

Comment: I have no problem.  Perhaps a cache clear is needed

Comment: I think it is because I am living in Shenzhen which is in China..
I have however used an external website (desmos) to make a drawing that you can view:

Comment: I have however used an external website (desmos) to make a drawing that you can view :https://www.desmos.com/geometry/gq8xv1yumt

Comment: Yes, that matches mine nicely.  My $D$ is the center of the circle.

Comment: I understand that the line from the origin to D (the center of the circle) is half the angle. But I don't understand what the relationship is with point P on the arc of the circle (where is point A from the triangle?)

Comment: You have $AP$ and the angle $ADP$.  Given the $x$ position of $D$, you can compute the $y$ position from the slope of $AD$, then compute the lengths $AD$ and $DP$.  That gives you three sides of a triangle and one angle.  They have to satisfy the law of cosines, so it is an equation in $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the line at angle $\theta$ is $$y=x\tan\theta$$
Let's call the coordinates of the center of the circle $(x_c,y_c)$. Then you know that the distance from the center to the line is equal to the distance from the center to point $P$ (note that this is on a parabola with focus $P$, and the directrix is the tilted line).
We write this as $$\frac{(x_c\tan\theta-y_c)^2}{\tan^2\theta+1}=(x_c-x_P)^2+(y_c-y_P)^2$$
I've used the formula on [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line), but you can just search for it. Since the circle touches the line and the $x$ axis, it means that the center is on the bisector of the angle. Therefore $$\tan\frac\theta 2=\frac{y_c}{x_c}$$
Take $y_c$ from the second equation, plug it into the first one, and you just get a quadratic. One of the solution corresponds to $P$ on the right side of the circle, one on the left. In your case, you want the smaller number.

Comment: Ross and Andrei, thank you very much.

Comment: However, the problem is more complicated as I originally said. Pleas see my modified original post

Answer (score 0):

For the modified problem, draw a vertical line through $C$. Since $C$ is on the diagonal, $x_C=y_C$. That's one of the unknowns. The second is the radius $r$. So you need two equations. One of them is the distance to point $P$:
$$(x_P-x_C)^2+(y_P-x_C)^2=r^2$$
For the other equation, look at the triangle formed by the $x$ axis, the upper line, and the vertical through $C$. This is a right angle triangle, with the angle at origin $\pi/4+\theta$, the opposite side is $x_C+r$, and the adjacent side $x_C$. Then the other equation is: $$\tan\left(\frac\pi4+\theta\right)=\frac{x_C+r}{x_C}$$
Eliminating $r$ from these two equations you get a quadratic in $x_C$. You need to choose the solution where $x_C<x_P$.